# Ayuda con esta full consulta - MySql

Tags: mysql

Tengo 5 tablas:

Tabla 1 - Usuarios

- código_usuario(PK)
- nombre
- apellido
- fecha_nacimiento
- sexo_usuario
- dirección_domicilio
- estado_civil
- numero_celular
- país_residencia
- foto_usuario

Tabla 2 - UsuariosCuentas

- código_cuenta(PK)
- código_usuario(FK)
- correo_electrónico
- clave_cuenta

Tabla 3 - Eventos

- código_evento(PK)
- fecha_evento
- hora_evento
- lugar_evento

Tabla 4 - EventosParticipantes

- código_evento_participante(PK)
- código_evento(FK)
- código_usuario(FK)
- estado

Tabla 5 - Miembros

- código_miembro(PK)
- código_evento_participante(FK)
- estado

Todos los usuarios que estén dentro de la tabla `EventosParticipantes` pasan a la tabla `Miembros`, es decir, si un usuario participa de un evento de capacitación, automáticamente se hace miembro de la institución.

Lo que deseo hacer es obtener un listado de todos los usuarios que estén dentro de la tabla `EventosParticipantes`, es decir, todos los usuarios que hayan sido participes de un evento de capacitación siempre y cuando el atributo `estado` sea 1, pero también se debe excluir a los usuarios que ya se encuentren en la tabla `Miembros` siempre y cuando su atributo sea 1, si es 0 se le debe incluir en los resultados. Los atributos `estados` que estoy manejando son para representar la actividad del usuario, sabemos que en base de datos no se deben eliminar registros, por lo que opte por usar atributos denominados `estado`, el 1 representa que el usuario esta activo y debe ser considerado en las consultas y el 0 representa que el usuario a sido eliminado y no debe ser considerado en las consultas

**Aun mas detallado**

En la aplicación que estoy desarrollando tengo un botón que es para agregar un nuevo Miembro, al presionar este botón se tiene que mostrar una lista en base a:

- Todos los usuarios que hayan sido participes de un evento y su estado sea 1.
- Si algún usuario ya se encuentra en la tabla miembros y su estado es 1, este debe ser excluido de la lista porque seria ilógico agregar a un usuario en la tabla miembros cuando este ya se encuentra agregado, pero si su estado es 0 este debe ser incluido en la lista.

Para ello hize la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT EventosParticipantes.codigo_evento_participante, Usuarios.foto_usuario, Usuarios.nombre, Usuarios.apellido, 
Usuarios.numero_celular, UsuariosCuentas.correo_electronico
FROM Usuarios
INNER JOIN EventosParticipantes ON Usuarios.codigo_usuario= EventosParticipantes.codigo_usuario
INNER JOIN UsuariosCuentas ON Usuarios.codigo_usuario = UsuariosCuentas .codigo_usuario 
WHERE EventosParticipantes.estado = 1
```

Esta consulta solo me devuelve los usuarios que están dentro de la tabla `EventosParticipantes` lo que me falta agregar es la exclusión o inclusión de los usuarios que ya son parte de la tabla Miembros de acuerdo a su estado, si es 1 excluimos, si es 0 incluimos. Ayúdenme a completar esta consulta por favor. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el operador `NOT IN` junto a una "mini-subconsulta" para excluir a los que ya son miembros:

```
SELECT EventosParticipantes.codigo_evento_participante, Usuarios.foto_usuario, Usuarios.nombre, Usuarios.apellido, 
Usuarios.numero_celular, UsuariosCuentas.correo_electronico
FROM Usuarios
INNER JOIN EventosParticipantes ON Usuarios.codigo_usuario= EventosParticipantes.codigo_usuario
INNER JOIN UsuariosCuentas ON Usuarios.codigo_usuario = UsuariosCuentas .codigo_usuario 
WHERE EventosParticipantes.estado = 1
  AND EventosParticipantes.código_evento_participante NOT IN (
        SELECT código_evento_participante
        FROM Miembros
        WHERE estado = 1
      )
```

Comment: Funciona, Gracias.